# Fastavro fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found for Mac M1

Tags: macos, fastavro

I am trying to install fastavro on my Mac M1 laptop, but got the error:

```
Headers -c fastavro/_read.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/fastavro/_read.o
      fastavro/_read.c:6:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastavro
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastavro, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

My python and system info is:

```
Python 3.9.6
virtualenv==20.16.6
% sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.6
BuildVersion:   21G115
```

Anyone has ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to overcome the same problem for `fastavro==1.7.0` but without luck. Eventually changed to the latest version (`pip install fastavro`) and 1.8.4 version of it was installed without any issues.